# Different notation for maxwell equations

Tags: maxwell-equations

I found in a book the Maxwell equations written in a form different that other books and wikipedia,

\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot E &=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\\
\nabla\cdot B &=0\\
\nabla \times E &=\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\\
\nabla \times B &=-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 c^2}J
\end{align}

Instead of what normally we see,
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot E &=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\\
\nabla\cdot B &=0\\
\nabla \times E &=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\\
\nabla \times B &=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 c^2}J
\end{align}

What meaning have this? And are they equivalent in some form? Or could this book have some error?

Comment: What book is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These equations are wrong.  Among other things, they do not obey charge conservation, since according to them
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \left(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B}\right) &=-\frac{1}{c^2}\vec{\nabla} \cdot \left( \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}\right) +\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 c^2} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} \\
0 &= -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}\right) +\frac{1}{\epsilon_0 c^2} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} \\
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon_0 c^2} \left( -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} \right)
\end{align*}
$$
This would imply that $\partial \rho/\partial t = \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J}$, which would mean (for example) that the charge density in a particular region of space would increase when a positive current flowed out of it.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have multiplied each of $B,\,J$ by $-1$.